# How can I (somewhat) evenly distribute dynamically-sized SVG shapes within a canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, svg, raphael

I'm looking for some high-level recommendations for how to implement a project I'm starting for a client.

This is a web page that will include an SVG canvas (sized 920px W x 450px H) containing 20-40 "circular" images (i.e., they may just be square images cropped with a circle). The size of the images will probably range from about 50px to about 200px diameter, each one set dynamically within that range based on data from an API. It's basically a dynamic data visualization, so pretty much every aspect of this needs to be configurable/dynamic.

I think the hardest problem to solve is how to distribute these images within the given canvas area, considering that they will vary in size, and should appear to be evenly/randomly distributed (i.e., they shouldn't line up to a grid, be clumped together, or be in groups of similar sizes). It's OK if they overlap slightly. Here's a quick sketch of how this should look, ideally (each gray circle represents an image):

https://skitch.com/troywarr/gwj14/adobe-fireworks-cs5

FWIW, I was planning to use [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) as an SVG library; I'll also have [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) available and can probably use any other libraries as needed. This needs to be cross-browser compatible back to IE7.

Can anyone suggest a general approach to this problem, any specific libraries or algorithms to look into, or provide any other guidance or suggestions? Please let me know if this description isn't clear, or if you need any additional details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Position the largest first, then fill in with successively smaller ones.  Probably you'd want to position the large ones, then "dither" them randomly a bit, to eliminate an appearance of rigidity.  Do the same with smaller ones, though "dither" less as they get smaller.  (Thankfully you don't want an "exact" solution, as I suspect the general problem is NP-complete.)

Comment: Thanks, Hot Licks - I appreciate your input. Yeah, a "looks good enough" solution is more than adequate. A few questions: How can I programmatically determine when one circle overlaps another? Do I just draw it in randomly, compare its radius with the radius of adjacent circles, and then erase and redraw it if it overlaps too much? Lastly, the bounding size of the images may need to depend on the canvas area available and the number of images desired - e.g., given a 920x450 canvas and 10 images to fit, they'll be larger overall; if I need to fit 30 images, they'll be smaller overall. How do...

Comment: ...I go about determining how large the largest image can be based on the area of the canvas and the number of images to fit? I may be overthinking this...

Comment: Like I said, any "exact" solution is likely to be NP-complete, so likely the best approximation is some sort of trial-and-error, with a few fudge factors thrown in.  Two circles overlap when `(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 < (radius1 + radius2)^2` (where `^2` means "squared").  As a first crack at the size of the images I'd just divide the total screen area by the number of images and multiply by some fudge factor.

Comment: What approach you end up using for this? I am trying to do something similar.

Comment: @Mutant, I described my approach in a new answer. Hope it helps - good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would tackle it:

First decide on the percentage of the screen that will be filled in with circles and the number of circles that will be displayed.  You can use that to determine the average radius of each circle using the area of a circle formula - e.g. given x circles what would the average radius of all the circles have to be to cover y% of my container.  You can then decide how much you want the radius to vary, that is +/- 50%.  Unless the number of circles is very small you should get a good result - statistically that is.

Then I would divide the screen in to a rectangular grid - I know that is not what you want just be patient :)  The dimensions of the grid are calculable from the number of circles, e.g. 16 circles would fit nicely into a 4 X 4 grid.  The number of circles can be less than the number of cells but not a lot less.

I would then select a random x,y co-ordinate inside each grid cell as my circle's center.  I would also leave a padding of about 25% around the edges so that my circle is not centered too close to an edge.

You could then check for overlap - the ratio of (r1 + r2) / distance between the circle center points will equal 1 if the circles touch, be less than 1 if they don't and greater than 1 if they overlap.  A ratio of 1.1 is a small overlap; careful of the limit here - exact same centers result in a distance of 0 and a division by 0 error.

One thing to worry about but should not happen unless you pick a very high initial coverage percentage or the number if circles is much smaller than the number of cells.  If all the cells adjacent to a given cell have circles close to that cells edges, especially if they overlap the edge, there may not be enough room (even with circle overlap) for the current cell's circle.  This can be checked for and handled by shrinking the radius or moving a circle away...

NOTE if the number of desired circle's does not exactly match your square (or rectangular) grid, just randomly leave some cells empty...

Comment: Thanks! That's a great answer, and is similar to the approach I ended up taking. I'll describe my approach in a separate answer, but you deserve the credit. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough description of the approach I took after all. Sorry, pressed for time so this may be inexact.

I initially approached the problem similarly to @BigMac66's answer. I laid out a grid corresponding to the quantity of circles I had, drew a circle in each and then randomly shifted the circles from the center point of each grid cell.

I built in a variety of "fudge factors" - circle radius bounds, offset from center, maximum overlap with adjacent cells, etc. - but, no matter how I tweaked my settings, you could still always tell that a grid was behind the layout; the circles aligned just enough to look like a wonky polka dot pattern rather than a truly random collection of circles.

So, I changed to a more brute-force approach.

First, I set up configurable bounds for the radius of a circle, tweaking the upper bound until I found a maximum size that didn't make the canvas look crowded based on the total number of circles I had.

Then, I applied my math to size the circles as needed (in short, the largest circles represented a 100% value, and the smallest represented a 0% value; the rest were sized accordingly based on where they fell in the spectrum).

Then, I sorted the circles descending by size. I laid them out randomly on the canvas, using an algorithm roughly like so:

1. Place a circle at random coordinates.
2. Place the next circle at random coordinates.
3. If the latter circle overlaps the former by more than X pixels (configurable param), place it at a new set of random coordinates.
4. Continue step #3 for up to Y times (another configurable param) until you successfully place another circle.
5. If you can't place the circle in Y times, clear the canvas, drop the maximum circle radius by Z pixels (another configurable param) and start over.

This worked surprisingly well, and I tweaked the params until I could draw the entire canvas very quickly while requiring few maximum circle radius reductions.

You can actually see the finished product here:

http://www.eonline.com/news/2012_sag_awards/heatgauge

It's out of season, so click the "Overall View" tab at the top of the main box to see cumulative stats (and hence a full canvas of circles).